# Webview onReceivedError called even if loading from cache

Tags: android, android-webview

I've set my Webview to cache every page it visits (while online). I also need to display a custom view on top of the Webview in case the device goes offline and the users tries to load a webpage and it's not been cached.

It seems that the `onReceivedError()` method of the `WebViewClient` class is called even if the page has been loaded from cache, and it sets the same error code, i.e. `-2` whick apparently means `ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP`

Is there a way to determine if the webpage failed and it was NOT loaded from cache, so I can then display a custom view to the user ? And no, I can't disable caching, I need to keep it.

Comment: Did you find an official solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I had to tackle this recently and hacked around it: I noticed that when loading cached content; the WebViewClient's onLoadResource() was called multiple times before onReceivedError(). When there was no cached content; onLoadResource() was only called once before onReceivedError().

I used this behaviour difference to set a flag which was used in onReceivedError() to determine if I should show my error view or not.

E.g:

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    private int onLoadResourceCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        onLoadResourceCount++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        if (onLoadResourceCount <= 1) {
            showErrorView();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: THIS IS A HACK AND IS BY NO MEANS A GOOD SUBSTITUTE FOR A WORKING API**...but this is the best I could do lacking one.

Answer (score 0):

This version is less hacky and still works. Use this to extend your `WebViewClient()`:

```
override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, error: WebResourceError) {
        if (request.url.toString() == view.url) {
             // showInternetConnectionError()
             webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error_state.html")
        }
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
}
```